# How is rational number a group under addition if some non-rational numbers can be represented as a sum of rational numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, irrational-numbers, infinite-groups

There are many famous examples demonstrating how adding rational numbers infinite times can give us non rational numbers notably the Basel problem:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

but on the other hand, in basic algebra course we are introduced that

$$ (\mathbb{Q}, + ) $$

is an infinite group under addition.

But how do I make sense of these two separate results? On one hand we add a "bunch" of rational numbers to get numbers outside $\mathbb{Q}$, but on the other hand under the group operation all elements in the set should give us elements within that set.

I suspect this has something to do with infinity.

Comment: Similarly, consider $$\sqrt{2} = 1.414^+,$$ which equals the limit of the infinite series $$1 + \frac{4}{10} + \frac{1}{100} + \frac{4}{1000} + \cdots $$

Comment: Groups don't have to be closed under the operation of infinite series, just finite sums.

Comment: That’s a *series*, not a *sum*.

Answer (score 8):

A series of the form $\sum_{n\ge1}n^{-2}$ is a *limit* of partial sums - but each $\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{-2}$ is a rational number.

Groups, with no additional topological structure, do not need to worry about limits. All you need is that $a+b$ is rational if $a,b$ are rational, and this is true. "Infinite group" means a group with infinitely many elements, it does *not* mean the group action can be composed infinitely many times.